# How to override class constructor?

Tags: angular

I have class Foo:

```
export class Foo {
   constructor(protected http: Http) {
   }
   ...
}
```

And class Bar that exdends class Foo:

```
export class Bar extends Foo {
   constructor(protected http: SecurityHttp) {
      super(http);
   }
   ...
}
```

The problem is that in class Bar angular injects invalid instance of Http (default Http instead of SecurityHttp).
When I try to make constructor in any component class with SecurityHttp it works well.

UPDATE:
SecurityHttp:

```
@Injectable()
export class SecurityHttp extends Http {

    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }
}
```

Module:

```
@NgModule({
   providers: [
        {
            provide: SecurityHttp,
            useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) => {
               return new SecurityHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, authService, router);
            },
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: So `SecurityHttp` doesn't extend `Http`?

Comment: SecurityHttp extends Http

Comment: Nevermind I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class BaseComponent {

  constructor(protected utilitiesService: UtilitiesService,
    protected loggingService: LoggingService) {
    this.logNavigation();
  }

  protected logError(errorMessage: string) { . . .}
  private logNavigation() { . . .}
} 


export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {

  constructor(private childDataService: ChildDataService,

  utilitiesService: UtilitiesService,

  loggingService: LoggingService) {

    super(utilitiesService, loggingService);

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answe. Please can you explain why this is the solution.

Comment: On the [answer] page you can find some tips to improve your answer.